# How to use the "url_dec" function in HAProxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, http-proxy, opnsense

I have a OPNSense firewall setup with HAproxy sitting on my WAN interface to reverse-proxy my web server. 
The problem with my application (which is outsourced) is that it has a lot of unicode characters in the URL parameters. Before installing OPNsense, I was running ISA server 2006 with no problems.

As I have read in its documentation, HAProxy only supports ASCII characters. However, I have a lot of non ascii characters which are written by design in the URL as URL parameters.
These characters include arabic characters and special french characters. 
 HAProxy considers these characters illegal, making the HTTP request invalid and returning error code 400 (Invalid request). After days of debugging and checking logs, I figured that this is the normal behavior of HAProxy.
One of the things I tried is to make HAProxy accept these characters, but It was not successful.

One last resort before trying another reverse proxy engine is to try to encode these characters in Javascript. But once I encode them, how do I decode them on the HAProxy configuration ? 
As is the HTTP response I am getting is 404 not found because the encoded URL parameters are not being decoded properly.

Any suggestions ?